# align item (that uses ':before') to the right

Tags: html, css

I have 2 icons that I need align to left and right edge of the site, the left is per default so my problem is align 'nextArrowIcon' item to right. I was trying using 'margin:auto' but it doesn't work. I need it work using ':before' selector.

Any help would be appreciated.

PD: I prefer avoid float solutions.

Here is the relevant code.

```css
 

h2#title{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 font-size:1.8em; 
 font-family:Patua One; 
 position:absolute;  
 left:50%;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.buttons{
 background:yellow;
}
.mainIcon:before{ 
 content:url("http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/main_icon_zpsrtoqnv5h.png"); 
}
.nextArrowIcon:before{ 
 content:url("http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/next_arrow_button_zps3skd2ok8.png"); 
 margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
  

<header id="carouselHeader">
 <h2 id="title">TITLE</h2>
 <div class="buttons">
  <a href="#"><i class="mainIcon"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="nextArrowIcon"></i></a>   
 </div>
</header>
```

And here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/pen/eZVKpB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each a tag into a DIV, and use absolute positioning to align `left` or `right`. HOWEVER, note that the parent div must be styled either `position:absolute` or `position:relative`. *Note that the default styling is `position:static`, which is almost identical to `position:relative`.*

```css
h2#title{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 font-size:1.8em; 
 font-family:Patua One; 
 position:absolute;  
 left:50%;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.buttons{
  position:relative;
 background:yellow;
}
#btnLeft {position:absolute;left:0;}
#btnRight{position:absolute;right:0;}
.mainIcon:before{  content:url("http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/main_icon_zpsrtoqnv5h.png"); 
}
.nextArrowIcon:before{ 
 content:url("http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/next_arrow_button_zps3skd2ok8.png"); 
 margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="carouselHeader">
 <h2 id="title">TITLE</h2>
 <div class="buttons">
      <div id="btnLeft">
  <a href="#"><i class="mainIcon"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div id="btnRight">
  <a href="#"><i class="nextArrowIcon"></i></a>   
      </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to ask one more thing. What is the reason behind use 'position:absolute' in the buttons?. I ask this because in this [pen](http://codepen.io/GhostOrder/pen/eZVKpB) I did not use absolute positioning to get the same result(div1 & 3 are the "buttons"), but for some reason in this code it doesn't work just by adding "margin-left:auto".

Comment: @GhostOrder checkout my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Add float:right such that:

```
.nextArrowIcon:before{  
content:url("http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/next_arrow_button_zps3skd2ok8.png"); 
margin-left:auto;
float:right;
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but I prefer not to uses float solutions, even so I would give you +1 but I need 15 rep : (

Comment: Glad it worked. Remember you can always clear floats with clear:both btw. :)

Answer (score 2):

what i have done is i just gave `.nextArrowIcon:before` property to float right  because by default it aligned left and i made background color `!important`. I didn't created any divs because you said,

> I need it work using ':before' selector.

So, you can try following,

Here's the [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNQrWm) example

```css
/********** FORMAT **********/
html, body, header, a, h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0; 
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
html{
 width:100%;
 background:white; 
 font-family:'Open Sans', serif;
 font-size:10px;  
}
/********* CONTENT *********/
h2#title{
 font-size:2.4em; 
 font-family:Patua One; 
 position:absolute;  
 left:50%;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.buttons{
 background:yellow !important; 
}


.mainIcon:before{ 
 margin:0;
content:url("http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/main_icon_zpsrtoqnv5h.png"); 
}
.nextArrowIcon:before{ 
float:right;
content:url("http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/next_arrow_button_zps3skd2ok8.png"); 
 margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="carouselHeader">
  <h2 id="title">TITLE</h2>
  <div class="buttons">
   <a href="#"><i class="mainIcon"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="nextArrowIcon"></i></a>   
  </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Thanks! it work. It's just that I prefer to avoid float solutions, I forgot mention it in my question.